# Why can I access a terminal command without sudo, but not with?

Tags: command-line, permissions, udev

I'm attempting to add `--add-udev-rule` to a specific program I've installed. I can access it by writing `thisismyprogram` in the terminal, which returns an error(Permissions etc.). Running `sudo thisismyprogram --add-udev-rule` results in `sudo: thisismyprogram: command not found`. What gives? I can access it without sudo, so why not with?

Comment: What is the path to `thisismyprogram`, and are you in the current directory when you try to run it?

Comment: It's in `~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/thisismyprogram` . I've tried running is from "any" directory as well as the above directory.

Comment: Does `sudo ~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/thisismyprogram` work?